# How to have an itemized list vertically in par with its heading

Tags: vertical-alignment, itemize

I'm trying to vertically align these two but the itemized list seems to start from the next line. How could I make them look in the same line?

```
\newcommand{\mhead}[1]{\leavevmode\marginpar{\sffamily\footnotesize #1}}
\bigskip
\mhead{Professional \newline Experiences}%
\begin{itemize}[label=$\diamond$]
\item item1
\item item2
\item item3
\end{itemize}
```

here is what it looks like now:
[image]

Comment: what about `\item\mhead{Professional \newline Experiences}
item1`?

Comment: and do you realy want to use `\marginpar`?

Comment: You should do this: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newcommand{\mhead}[1]{\marginnote{\sffamily\footnotesize #1}}
\reversemarginpar
\begin{document}
\lipsum
\begin{itemize}[label=$\diamond$]
\item item1 \mhead{Professional \\ Experiences}%
\item item2
\item item3
\end{itemize}
\end{document}`

Comment: `\item\mhead{...}item1` (without space after the macro)

Comment: @Fran Thnx, it did work.

Comment: @Fran Could you write an answer to close this?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

As stated in the comments,`\mhead{}` should be inside the first item. Any place within the item is good as long it remains in the first line. Therefore the safest place is just after `\item`,  but note that space after the macro is not ignored, i.e., use `\item\mhead{}xxx` or `\item \mhead{}xxx` but not `\item\mhead{} xxx`

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem,xcolor,libertine}
\usepackage[lmargin=3in]{geometry}  
\newcommand{\mhead}[1]{%
\leavevmode\marginpar{\footnotesize\textsc{\textcolor{red!50!black}{#1}}}}
\def\mrule{\marginpar{\color{gray!40}\rule{6cm}{1pt}}}
\reversemarginpar

\begin{document}

\mrule

\begin{itemize}[label=$\diamond$, leftmargin=-4em]
\item \mhead{Professional \newline Experiences}item1
\item item2
\item item3
\end{itemize}

\mrule

\end{document}
```